# Select different values into a table

Tags: sql, sql-server

Now I know how to select the outputs of a column into a table

```
select column1, column2 into #temptable
```

now, what if I just want to input the values myself into the table?

I know that

```
select 'a' [column1] into #temptable
```

works

and

```
select 'a' [column1] into #temptable
union
select 'b' [column1]
```

also works

but surely there's a less braindead way to get multiples lines of text into a row in SQL.

Comment: I added the SQL Server tag based on the syntax.

Comment: Please add a tag for your databasesystem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Demo on db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=7e771b600f9848b7ce05d5b6d13ae05d)

You might need ***Desired table***

```
select v.value
into #temptable
from (
    values ('a'), ('b'), ('c')
)v(value);
```

or

```
select 'a' as Value
into #temptable2

insert into #temptable2
values ('b'), ('c')
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you just want `values()`?

```
select v.*
into #temptable
from (values ('a'), ('b')) v(column1);
```